# ElasticSearch Synonym returning multiple results

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have in my index two documents:

```
{
  "name": "dog"
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": "dog - hypoallergenic"
}
```

I've created a synonym mapping file like follows:

```
PUT syn_test
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_synonym_filter": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms": ["puppy=>dog","canine=>dog","kitten=>cat","feline=>cat"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_synonyms": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_synonym_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "animal": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I've indexed two documents:

```
POST syn_test/animal
{
  "name": "dog - hypoallergenic"
}

POST syn_test/animal
{
  "name": "dog"
}
```

When I search for `puppy` or `canine`, which are mapped as synonyms for `dog` in my index mapping, I get results for both `dog` and `dog - hypoallergenic`.

My desired output for a query of `puppy` or `canine` would just return `dog`. Is there a way to force the query to return only exact matches from the synonym?

Answer (score 0):

You have used standard tokenizer. If you want to consider name as only single valued field(just like it is provided) you can specify keyword tokenizer instead of standard.